# SQL how to If a combination of numbers is in a table

Tags: sql

I have a list of id's (numbers) that if that number is used it equals a higher value. the numbers are not chronological. Ex:
100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 151, 125, 126, 152, 155, 156, 158, 160, 153, 166, 167, 120.

If i have a set of values (103, 126) both fall into above table I want a result of "good"
If I have a set of values (103, 59) not all numbers are not in the table then "fail"

Do I have to write a iif for every combination?

I have tried a IN statement,
select user, usercode
from usertable
where usercode in (100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 151, 125, 126, 152, 155, 156, 158, 160, 153, 166, 167, 120)

Comment: [tag:sql] is quite unspecific; which RDBMS are you using in actuality? Answers can differ materially between each. Can you share the exact text of the queries you've tried, what you expected to happen when you tried each, and what *actually* happened when you ran each of them? What errors did you see? Can you include their texts in the question as well? See [ask]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using TSQL.

Let's set up some example data (It's super helpful if you do this in your question).

```
DECLARE @numbers TABLE (ID INT)
DECLARE @rnd INT

WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @numbers) < 25
BEGIN
SET @rnd = ROUND(((50 - 1 -1) * RAND() + 1), 0) - 1
INSERT INTO @numbers (ID)
 SELECT @rnd  WHERE @rnd NOT IN (SELECT * FROM @numbers WHERE ID = @rnd)
END
```

This creates a table variable which contains 25 randomly picked INTs between 0 and 50.

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN n.id IS NOT NULL AND n2.id IS NOT NULL THEN 'FOUND THEM BOTH!' 
               WHEN n.id IS NULL AND n2.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 'FOUND ONLY Y!'
               WHEN n2.id IS NULL AND n.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 'FOUND ONLY X!'
               ELSE 'FOUND NEITHER!'
           END AS result
  FROM (VALUES ((ROUND(((50 - 1 -1) * RAND() + 1), 0) - 1),(ROUND(((50 - 1 -1) * RAND() + 1), 0) - 1))) a(x,y)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @numbers n
      ON a.x = n.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @numbers n2
      ON a.y = n2.ID
```

This picks two random numbers between 0 and 50 and looks for them in the example data table variable.
In this case I used two LEFT OUTER joins so we always get a result, and a case statement to parse the result into a string. The results will be one of

- 'FOUND THEM BOTH!' - both numbers existed in the table.
- 'FOUND ONLY X!' - Just the X value was found in the table.
- 'FOUND ONLY Y!' - Just the Y value was found in the table.
- 'FOUND NEITHER!' - Neither number was found in the table.

This is a good demo on how sometimes you'll need to join a single table twice, and that's just fine, just remember to alias it